# Weird Results A/B Test in Google Website Optimizer

Tags: testing, a-b-testing, google-website-optimizer

I set up a test in Google Website Optimizer that has a 3 variations - original (A), B, and C. In order to further validate the results of the test, I added a variation C that is exactly the same as the original. And thats where the results get weird.

6 days into the test, the best performing variation is C. It outperforms the original by 18.4%! How is that possible?

Do I now discount the results of this test entirely?

Comment: How many times has the test been run? Then we can work out the expected variation between A and C.

Comment: Each variation has had about 480 visits and between 74-91 conversions

Answer (score 2):

Not enough experiments or divergence in the results to be statistically significant yet.  Try doing a Google search on AB Testing confidence and work out what sort of confidence level you're at with your experiment.  This will give you a much better idea of whether your results are significant or whether you should just let the experiment run longer.

Speaking from personal experience I cannot tell you how many times I've tested an altered landing page layout that instantly showed a huge improvement in an AB test in the first day or two.  But then as the amount of data increases my "improvement" turned out to be a pipe dream/

Answer (score 0):

If C was displayed to visitors even a small percentage over A it would have a higher conversion rate. With now 3 variations you cannot distribute your traffic evenly, so there's probably always one variation with slightly more views than another.

I often use the multivariate tool with a single variation for A/B tests on dynamic pages.

6 days is also a short amount of time even with a few hundred visits. But that also depends on what your conversion is considered. Leaving the tests to run a month or more is ideal to start to see a steady pattern. In the beginning of tests it's common to see variations bouncing up and down with conversions. After a while the lines steady out and you'll see a clear winner.

I suggest not adding a variation that is the exact same as your test / original page

Comment: "I suggest not adding a variation that is the exact same as your test / original page" - why? the entire purpose was to see if there is a difference in conversion rate between the A and C, even though they are exactly the same

Comment: "If C was displayed to visitors even a small percentage over A it would have a higher conversion rate." - I don't understand this either. Why would C have a higher conversion rate just because its displayed a bit more?

Comment: Would you post your website optimizer report from beginning to end so we can see the stats?